# How can I force Mathematica to take the dot product here?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

The code:

```
vec1 = {{-1}, {0}, {1}} // MatrixForm
vec2 = {{-1}, {1}, {0}} // MatrixForm
p[v2_, v1_] := v1 (v1.v2)/Sqrt[(v1.v1) (v2.v2)];
u2 = vec2 - p[vec2, vec1]
```

The output:

[image]

Mathematica won't calculate the dot product in the output. I've tried `Simplify`, `FullSimplify`, `Reduce`, and `MatrixForm.` The last two were total guesses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the extra braces inside the vectors, such that the code becomes

```
vec1 = {-1, 0, 1}
vec2 = {-1, 1, 0}
p[v2_, v1_] := v1 (v1.v2)/Sqrt[(v1.v1) (v2.v2)];
u2 = vec2 - p[vec2, vec1]
```

Comment: That was it, thanks!